# Idea doesn't upgrade sources while in local debug for appEngine app

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I created `Spring Boot` + `Google App Engine` application. For development purpose I use `IntelliJ IDEA` and `Google Cloud Tools` plugin. I'm currently using only localDebug, which means I don't deploy anything on Google cloud. The configuration for debug is below:

[image]

I created a simple service to be sure if my code is updated on change or not:

```
static int i = 10;
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
public String test() {
    return Integer.toString(++i);
}
```

Unfortunately when I change my code (e.g. from `i = 10` to `i = 100`) and restart the app (I mean press on `Rerun (Ctrl+F5)` or `Stop (Ctrl+F2)` + `Run` my code doesn't apply on server, which means Idea doesn't rebuild the sources on server start.  As you see on the screenshot above I even tried to add `Build Project` step to `Before launch`, which didn't work.

- So to apply changes I need to execute from command line `mvn appengine:run` -> press `Ctrl+C` to stop it, switch to IDEA and start debug again which is a pain in the ass.
- Another option is to use `Hot Reload` (Update application, `Ctrl+F10`). It recompiles only changed classes and reloads resources. This is a cool feature, but unfortunately it doesn't work in a lot of cases which makes me unable to use it as a reliable reload.

Is there anything I can do to force IDEA compile my sources? Is it a bug I should report to plugin developer. Or maybe appengine uses some additional remote sources that require explicit call of maven?

Comment: hi @deathangel908. I am contributor to the google cloud tools plugin. Sorry for the simplistic suggestion, but just to rule it out, are you sure your browser isn't caching the previous state of the page (force a refresh of the browser or clear the cache to see)?

Comment: @eshaul yep, I'm 100% sure, I found the solution, take a look at my answer please, maybe this should be marked as a bug or I was doing smth wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. As I understood the `Google cloud plugin` just complies the classes into `target/classes` but when it starts the `appEngine`, the engine expected unpacked `.war` to be present under `target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

E.g. if because if I delete both directories I get the error below:

[image]

To solve the issue I needed to compile those sources:

- In toolbar `Run` -> `Edit configuration`
- Select `Google App Engine Standard Local server`
- In  before launch add `Build Artifact` -> `demo:war exploded` where demo is the name of your App.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for these details. Oddly, the local dev run config should have created that 'before launch' task automatically for you. I've opened an issue on our tracker: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/1785 so we can follow up there. Could you post any more details about your project (are you using Maven, is it a multi-module setup, etc.) on the github issue?